Automation code for Google Sheets and Doc Template
Full disclosure, I am a noob where Google Apps Script and coding is concerned. While I feel that I have managed to fill out quite a few elements in the code myself, I either keep getting errors, or the Doc template will duplicate as only blank pages.
My goal with the code is to automatically insert client data (as it is updated in a master Google Spreadsheet), copy a Google Doc from a template file, replace client data using replaceText, and save and close the file. Bonus: If I can get the code to generate the URL of the new client Doc and insert the new Doc URL into the Spreadsheet and/or if I can make it so that I don't have to enter "Y" to trigger the contract to generate.
The file name I am trying to name as "Business Name" (data located in the Spreadsheet at contractData[i][3]) + Business Plan Agreement. Though, the code is not renaming the file and only showing "contractData[i][3] Business Plan Agreement" as the file name.
Currently, I am getting error messages indicating

Type Error: newDoc.getBody is not a function

or

makeCopy is not a valid function.

I am struggling to understand why these errors are happening.
While I feel like I am 'close' to solving this puzzle, I also feel like this project will make me pull my hair out.
Any and all guidance is greatly appreciated! If there is anything that I should have included in my explanation, or if anything requires clarification, please let me know.
Link to Sheet: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XeQ0xWNO5tWQMXYhIZtU6TVWqbKDRrGPc7b6rebiQp8/edit?usp=sharing)
function generateContracts() {

// Define Spreadsheet and template ID

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses (Copy)");
const contractData = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
const contractTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById("Template ID");
const myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID");
let today = new Date();
const fileName = "contractData[i][3]" + "Business Plan Agreement.gdoc"

// Rename the copied file and Replace variables in new Google Doc file

for (let i = 1; i < contractData.length; i++)
if(contractData[i][0] == "Y") {
let myDoc = DocumentApp.openById("Template ID");
let newDoc = contractTemplate.makeCopy(fileName);

let docBody = newDoc.getBody();    
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][3]"+"}}", contractData[i][3]);
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][1]"+"}}", contractData[i][1]);
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][2]"+"}}", contractData[i][2]);
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][5]"+"}}", contractData([i][5]));
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][6]"+"}}", contractData([i][6]));
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][7]"+"}}", contractData([i][7]));
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][8]"+"}}", contractData([i][8]));
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][9]"+"}}", contractData([i][9]));
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][10]"+"}}", contractData([i][10]));
docBody.replaceText("{{"+"contractData[0][14]"+"}}", contractData([i][14]));

newDoc.saveAndClose
DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolder).addFile(newDoc);  
}

}

I have tried using GS Copilot, Youtube videos, and browsing previous questions and answers in Stack Overflow. I have tried modifying my code to incorporate answers from different sources, though, I have not yet been successful in trying to get my code to work.

Please make you spreadsheet accessible to all users.

Type Error: newDoc.getBody is not a function in short, you have mixed commands between DriveApp and DocumentApp. newDoc is based on DriveApp (const contractTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById("Template ID");) . OTOH, getBody requires DocumentApp.

@Tedinoz, I have changed the spreadsheet's accessibility setting. Thank you for bringing it to my attention!
For the Template ID in these two cases, I had been using the same ID using the Google Doc File ID. How should I structure the syntax to ensure the Doc Template file opens in each case?
How should I structure the getBody function to open and make a copy of the contract template?

You want to merge a template document with some spreadsheet data, rename the template document, and save it to a new file. Your script is complete but not working as expected.
Two errors are specifically noted but there are others:

Type Error: newDoc.getBody is not a function

getBodyis a Document method, but newDoc is derived from DriveApp. They are not transferrable.


makeCopy is not a valid function.

It is not clear why this is failing. For example, we don't know the value of "i", and we don't have access to to template file. However... the answer uses the same code and does not get this error.



Consider this answer based on the script. The key differences are noted:

const contractData = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues() - the actual number of rows of data = 2 (including the header) however the first 100 rows of Column A are populated with a formula. getDataRange recognises the formulas and creates an array that includes 99 rows of blank data.

the answer calculates the actual number of data rows and defines an appropriate range.


let today = new Date() - declared but never used

const fileName = "contractData[i][3]" + "Business Plan Agreement.gdoc" - used before "I" is declared.

let myDoc = DocumentApp.openById("Template ID") - declared but never used

let newDocID = newDoc.getId() - a new line

gets the document ID for the copy of the template from DriveApp


let newTemplate = DocumentApp.openById(newDocID) - a new line

opens the new created copy of the Template


docBody.replaceText... - the purpose of these 10 lines of code is to create search text based on the header value. But these lines fail for one of two reasons:

the quotation marks around contractData[0][3] which result in a value of "{{contractData[0][3]}}" versus, say, "{{First Name}}".
contractData([i][5])) - the replacement text in the last seven lines includes curley brackets around the array arguments. It should read like: contractData[i][5])


DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolder).addFile(newDoc); - this line is intended to move the newly merged file to the target folder. However there is no such command as addFile()

the line should read: DriveApp.getFileById(newDocID).moveTo(myFolder)




function generateContracts() {

  // Define Spreadsheet and template ans folder IDs

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses (Copy)");
  // set key variables
  var templateID = "<<insert Template ID>>" // ID of the document Template
  const contractTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID);
  var folderID = "<<insert Folder ID>>" // id of the folder to save the merged templates
  const myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

  // get the data
  // get the number of rows of data
  var aVals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var aLast = aVals.filter(String).length;
  // get the data (including the header row)
  const contractData = sheet.getRange(1,1,aLast,16).getValues()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+sheet.getRange(1,1,aLast,16).getA1Notation())

  // Rename the copied file and Replace variables in new Google Doc file
  // loop through the data to build the file from the template
  // Note: start with i=1 to exclude the header row
  for (let i = 1; i < contractData.length; i++){

  // test for Generate = Y
  if(contractData[i][0] == "Y") {
    // build the Document file name
    const fileName = contractData[i][3] + "Business Plan Agreement.gdoc"
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", the file name will be "+contractData[i][3] + "Business Plan Agreement.gdoc")
    // copy the template to the new file name (a DriveApp method)
    let newDoc = contractTemplate.makeCopy(fileName)
    // get the ID of the new file (a Drive App method)
    let newDocID = newDoc.getId() // get the ID of the new file
    // open the new document file (a DocmentApp method)
    let newTemplate = DocumentApp.openById(newDocID)

    // get the Body of the new file and replace the text with array values
    let docBody = newTemplate.getBody();    
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][3]+"}}", contractData[i][3]);
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][1]+"}}", contractData[i][1]);
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][2]+"}}", contractData[i][2]);
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][5]+"}}", contractData[i][5]);
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][6]+"}}", contractData[i][6]);
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][7]+"}}", contractData[i][7]);
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][8]+"}}", contractData[i][8]);
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][9]+"}}", contractData[i][9]);
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][10]+"}}", contractData[i][10]);
    docBody.replaceText("{{"+contractData[0][14]+"}}", contractData[i][14]);

    // save and close the new document
    newDoc.saveAndClose
    // move the new document to the target folder (A DriveApp method)
    DriveApp.getFileById(newDocID).moveTo(myFolder)
  
    }
  }
}


SAMPLE - Template

SAMPLE - Merged File

